# SQL Server: Secondary query on empty rowset from first query

Tags: sql, sql-server

say I have the following simple table

table a
{
   id int,
   pointId int,
   state int,
   value int
}

```
id    pointId     state   value
-------------------------------
1     1           2       xxxxx
2     3           2       xxxxx
3     3           2       xxxxx
4     3           1       xxxxx
```

with the following two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE state = 1 and pointId = x
SELECT * FROM a WHERE state = 2 and pointId = x
```

Is there a way to combine the two queries so that:

- if query 1 returns >0 rows, it returns the result from query 1
- if query 1 returns 0 rows, it returns the result from query 2

(so for pointId = 1 it would return row 1, for pointId = 3 it would return row 4)

I've been trying to combine the two with a union doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE state = 1 AND pointId = x
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM a WHERE state = 2 AND pointId = x and 
pointId NOT IN (SELECT pointId FROM a WHERE state = 1 AND pointId = x)
```

I'm wondering if I'm making this way to complicated and if there's a more easy way. I realize I could just run the first query and then handle it in my code, but it would be really nice if I could do this in the sql.
Any advice or pointers would be great!

Thanks,

A

Comment: You shouldn't use UNION in this case.  You are not looking to combine records - you are looking to process either query 1 or query 2 based on `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` is used to combine tuples, your specification mentions you want to return 1 set of tuples or another set of tuples.  In this case you don't want to use `UNION`, you can use `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS(...insert your first query here...)
    BEGIN
       --a record exists process first query
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
         --do other query
    END
```

Comment: Right:) However, that would execute the query twice no? The table a from my example is a huge table in reality and I was wondering if there's a way to avoid doing the query twice... (but thanks a lot already!)

Comment: You aren't processing or returning the `EXISTS` clause.  You are checking if a record exists.  What you could also do is check if the count > 0 `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Query1` and if that returns > 0 execute query 1 else execute query 2.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the best answer in terms of maintenance and performance.
Source:https://stackoverflow.com/a/12981314

```
WITH query1 AS (
    SELECT ...
),
query2 AS (
    SELECT ...
)
SELECT *
    FROM query1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
    FROM query2
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM query1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case in your question you could do

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY state) AS R
         FROM   a
         WHERE  state IN ( 1, 2 )
                AND pointId = x)
SELECT id,
       pointId,
       state,
       value
FROM   T
WHERE  R = 1;
```

More generally if Query 1 is potentially expensive you could just execute it and then check `@@ROWCOUNT` afterwards to know whether to execute Query 2.

This means your application needs to handle multiple result sets. If you don't want to handle that the first query could be inserted to a table variable then you only do the `SELECT` from that if `@@ROWCOUNT > 0`